# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in Magento 2.4.3

Tags: php, magento2

```
protected function _saveAppliedTaxes(
        Address $address,
        $applied,
        $amount,
        $baseAmount,
        $rate
    ) {
        $previouslyAppliedTaxes = $address->getAppliedTaxes();
        $process = count(($previouslyAppliedTaxes));

        foreach ($applied as $row) {
            if ($row['percent'] == 0) {
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: `var_dump($previouslyAppliedTaxes)` to check what type of variable it is. Like the error describes, it must be an array or an object implementing the `Countable` interface, but in this case it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Specified warning is printed when you pass non-array to `count()`. For example:

```
<?php

var_dump(count(null));

?>

PHP Warning:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /root/a.php on line 4
int(0)
```

You can suppress warnings by calling `error_reporting(0)`:

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);
var_dump(count(0));

?>

int(1)
```

However, it is wiser to check `getAppliedTaxes()` result and act accordingly.

```
$previouslyAppliedTaxes = $address->getAppliedTaxes();
$process = is_countable($previouslyAppliedTaxes) ?  count($previouslyAppliedTaxes): 0;
```

One more note, if we check Address model source:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/42fe2238acccfd90312c67f2c9ad2702b4a4e6f2/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php#L1241

we can find out that `getAppliedTaxes()` returns either a result of deserialization or an empty array, and as `count([])` emits no warning, seems that errorneous non-countable value was somehow stored to the session previously.

E.g. there's some part in your code that gives wrong value to the `setAppliedTaxes()`, that might indicate another bug, you should debug there, try dumping the value if it is non-countable and analyse your code to see where can it came from.

```
function var_dump_str($var)
{
    ob_start();
    var_dump($var);
    return ob_get_clean();
}


...


protected function _saveAppliedTaxes(
...


$previouslyAppliedTaxes = $address->getAppliedTaxes();
if (!is_countable($previouslyAppliedTaxes)) {
   error_log("DEBUG: previouslyAppliedTaxes is non-countable: type is ". type($previouslyAppliedTaxes) . ", value is '" . var_dump_str($previouslyAppliedTaxes) . "', and last JSON error was '" . json_last_error() . "'", 0)
}
```